# Using output of one task as an input for another

Tags: gruntjs

I have an html file that contains references to js files. I want to parse it extract a list of referenced js files and feed `contrib-concat` or any other task with them. 
Is there any convenient  way to use output of one grunt task as an input for another?

Comment: You can use [grunt-usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin), I'm not really familiar with it but it seems to me like it will provide you with what you need. and yes you can use the output of one task as the input of another if you put the output of task a in a tmp_dir and point the input of the second task to thet tmp_dir, hope this help.

Comment: Yes, I saw grunt-usemin but it doesn't provide flexibility. One can use it only with concat/uglify and all this task is a bit complicated. Thanks for idea with temp_dir it may work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [grunt.config](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config). Here is an example:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  concat: {
    js: {
      src: ['default/concat/files/*'],
      dest: ['dist/javascript.js'],
    },
  },
});
grunt.registerTask('extractjs', function() {
  /* Do the js extraction */
  // Overwrite the concat.js.src with your extracted files.
  grunt.config(['concat', 'js', 'src'], extractedFiles);
});
```

So now when you run `grunt extractjs concat` it will extract the js and then concat the extracted js files. Check out this task: https://github.com/cgross/grunt-dom-munger as he is working on a similar goal. Here is a grunt issue with more examples as well: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/747